# property not holding onto value

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a property in my view controller (the app only has one view controller)

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString * correctAnswer;
```

In viewDidLoad, I set that property like this and the log statement confirms that it's being set

```
self.correctAnswer = info.correctAnswer;
NSLog(@"correctAnswer %@", self.correctAnswer);
```

However, when I click a button in the view and try to inspect that same property in the action (in the same view controller) triggered by the button, it's turning out to be `(null)` Therefore the string comparison is always wrong. Can you explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
- (IBAction)checkResponse:(UIButton *)sender {

    UIButton *resultButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSLog(@" The button's title is %@.", resultButton.currentTitle);
    NSLog(@"correct answer %@", self.correctAnswer);  //null

    if ([resultButton.currentTitle isEqualToString:self.correctAnswer]){
        NSLog(@"you guessed right");
    }else {
        NSLog(@"You guessed wrong");

    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the property from `weak` to `strong` (or better yet in this case, `copy`).

Weak properties are set to `nil` as soon as the referenced object is deallocated.

Comment: Thanks, at what point would that referenced object have been deallocated if I only did the one assignment to it?